# Twilio throws access denied error when trying to access by using fetch method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, twilio, sms

Good Evening,
I am experimenting with using APIs and rendering that data in an EJS template.
I am trying to get a specific message from Twilio using the URL.
I downloaded node-fetch so I can use fetch with nodejs.
If I use the URL Twilio wants me to use it says access denied.
URL: [https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{Account](https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/%7BAccount) Sid}/Messages/{Message Id};

If I put my auth token in before or after the account sid, it says that it cant find the message.
URL: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{Account Sid}/{Auth token}/Messages/{Message Id}';

I have added my nodejs code below, any help is much appreciated.

```js
/* Imports */
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

/* .env import */
require('dotenv').config();

/* This parses the JSON from the AJAX req */
router.use(bodyParser.json());


/* Inputing the API keys for Twilio, they are in a .env file */
var accountSid = process.env.ACCOUNT_SID; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/console
var authToken = process.env.AUTH_TOKEN;   // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

/* Creating boilerplate Twilio */
var twilio = require('twilio');
const { data } = require('jquery');
var client = new twilio(accountSid, authToken); 


/* GET home page */
router.get('/',  async (req, res, next) => {
  const url_api = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{Account Sid}/Messages/{Message Id}';
 
 
  /* Test */
  const test = 'https://httpbin.org/get'

  try {
    await fetch(url_api)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        const body = body;
        console.log(body);
        res.render('index', {
          body: body
        }); 
      })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
    
 
}); 


  /*Twilio 
  1. Create a message on Twilio and send the message
  2. The body is JSON from the AJAX request 
  */
router.post('/',   (req, res, next) => {
    
      client.messages.create({
        body: `${req.body.message}`,
        to: `${req.body.number}`,  // Text this number
        from: process.env.PHONE_NUMBER // From a valid Twilio number
    })
        .then((message) => console.log(message.sid)); 

    next();
     
 
}) 



module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Why not use the actual Twilio client? `client.messages(<some message id>).fetch().then(...)`.

Comment: you need to pass `accountSid` and `authToken` in the request `Authorization` header - but it makes more sense to use the twilio library as per above comment

Comment: I used the client.messages.fetch.then and I got the specific message, which is perfect. Do you have any suggestions on how I would get any message that is sent to the Twilio number and not have to manually input the message-id in?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource?code-sample=code-read-list-messages-matching-filter-criteria&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x

Comment: This may seem stupid but I don’t see how that would help. I’m not trying to list the messages received. Any time a message comes to the twilio number I want to render it in my ejs template. If I’m going by this link above I would use it to get the message Id and run a function that captures the id and renders it in my template.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of working with the API, I found the solution.
The try method is where the magic happens. This gets the most recent message sent to the Twilio number and allows the body of the message to be available to the EJS template

```js
/* GET home page */
router.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  const url_api = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{Account Sid}/Messages/SM025191920c117b50102d09f0c1200ed3.json';

 
  /*The try is where the magic happens. This gets the most recent message sent to the Twilio number and allows the body of the message to be available to the EJS template*/
  try {
    client.messages
      .list({
        from: '+17185412931',
        limit: 1
      })
      .then(messages => messages.forEach(m => 
        res.render('index', {
          messagesId: m.body
        })));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }


});
```